# weird if-then behavior in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I have this code:

```
    System.out.println(staff.getEmail().length());
    System.out.println(staff.getEmailList());
    if ((staff.getEmail().length() > 0) && (staff.getEmailList() == "Y")) {
        System.out.println(staff.getEmail());
```

This is the output on my eclipse console:

```
12
Y
```

My problem is that even though both conditions in the if statement are satisfied, my program can never get to the last line of code above (System.out.println(staff.getEmail())). I don't any error too.

Any ideas what could I've done wrong? thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and not operator == for string equality in java.

`staff.getEmailList() == "Y"` should be converted into `"Y".equals(staff.getEmailList())`

The reason for it is `operator==` checks for *identity*. If the two operands are the same object (referencing to the same object), while `equals()` checks for *equality* - if the two operands equal each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here you compare not actualy string values, but their references (pointers in C-language).

```
(staff.getEmailList() == "Y")
```

You should do this

```
(staff.getEmailList().equals("Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the comparison `staff.getEmailList() == "Y"` you are asking if the two strings are the same `String` instances, not if they have the same value. YOu you should `staff.getEmailList().equals("Y")` instead.